# Connecting to MySQL from C or C++

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I need to write a C or C++ program that connects to a MySQL server and displays the global timezone.

Is there any connector needed for doing this? I think `mysql.h` header file should be included for doing this. Is that right?

Comment: Did you try to do so by yourself?

Comment: Writing a multi-language source file is hard! I suggest you keep yourself to either C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use C/C++, then yes, you need to use a C or C++ connector to query the server.

[SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

If this is all you want to do, it is much easier to do it in a shell script, Ruby, Python, php, or a myriad of other scripting languages.

Comment: You also must link with libmysql, which is the connector itself.

Comment: True, he will also have to deal with the compiler, the linker, and perhaps a Makefile - none of which is required with a shell script or a scripting language.